# Can't access my service in my controller (undefined)

Tags: angularjs, angular-services

I am trying to create a service to do some AJAX requests.
However, my service keeps getting undefined when I try to do something with it in my controllers. Here is my code.

I have found a lot of examples on here, and I've tried to follow a lot of them but no matter what I do my service keeps getting undefined.

My service:

```
MyApp.factory('myService', function($http) {

return {
    findAll: function() {
        return $http.get('/findAll')
        .then(function(result) {
            return result.data;
        });
    }
   }
});
```

My Controller:

```
MyApp.controller('UserController', ['$scope', '$http', 'myService', function($scope, $http, $log, myService) {

// Whatever I do with myService here it gets undefined.
//$scope.test = myService.findAll();
//myService.findAll();


}]);
```

I assume I don't inject it correctly but I can't see whats wrong. I'm fairly new to Angular so..
Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure the service is `undefined` and not the result of `myService.findAll()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `$log` from the injection. You are currently "naming" the `myService` service to `$log` and therefore `myService` inside the controller is `undefined`.

```
MyApp.controller('UserController', ['$scope', '$http', 'myService',
    function($scope, $http, myService) {

    // Whatever I do with myService here it gets undefined.
    //$scope.test = myService.findAll();
    //myService.findAll();
}]);
```

---

**2nd solution**
To avoid having to "name" the services like this it's acceptable to inject them without naming them.

```
MyApp.controller('UserController', function($scope, $http, myService) {

    // Whatever I do with myService here it gets undefined.
    //$scope.test = myService.findAll();
    //myService.findAll();
});
```

Just remember to remove the closing bracket aswell.

Comment: simpe - Wow, I didn't know that.. would never have thought of it. Thanks a lot! Accepted.

Comment: No problem, glad it helped. If you want to avoid having to "name" the services you can just inject them without naming them. Will update answer to show how. Happy holidays!

Comment: simple - Thank you. I actually think I prefer the 2nd solution. Happy holidays!

Comment: Actually, it not only is simpler, it is *better*. You avoid repeating yourself (DRY). The only problem is when you minify, so use ng-annotate.