# angularjs and requirejs, how to use service from another module?

Tags: angularjs, requirejs

I'm trying to create a simple demo, where my App Module inherits another module("testModule") and then calls startCtrl controller in the view to alert a message. This code is using require js also. The error i'm getting is:

Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope <- testService

on a side note i'm trying to plug in a reusable module. i.e. testModule to the main App module, which this demo will use throughout.

**HTML**

```
<body ng-app="app">  
   <div ng-controller="StartCtrl">
      <input type="button" ng-click="alertUser()" value="AlertUser">
   </div>

     <script data-main="js/main.js" src="~/Scripts/require.js"></script>
 </body>
```

**main.js**

```
require.config({
paths: {
    'angular': "../Scripts/angular",
    'angular-route': "../Scripts/angular-route",
    'angularAMD': "../Scripts/angularAMD",
    'jquery': "../Scripts/jquery-1.8.2",
},
shim: {
    jquery: {
        exports: '$'
    },
    'angular': ['jquery'],
    'angularAMD': ['angular'],
    'angular-route': ['angular'],



},
   deps: ['app']
});
```

**app.js**

```
define(['angularAMD', 'angular', 'angular-route', 'NewFeature/main'],   function (angularAMD) {

     var app =  angular.module('app', ['testModule','ngRoute']);

     return angularAMD.bootstrap(app);


 });
```

**NewFeature/main**

```
define(['./testModule','./testService','./feature']);
```

**feature.js file**

```
define(['angular','./testModule','ngAnimate', 'angular-route'], function () {
angular.module('testModule').controller('StartCtrl, function ($scope, testService) {
    $scope.alertUser = function () {
        testService.alertService();
    }

  }])
```

});

**testService.js**

```
define(['./testModule','jquery','angular'], function ($) {

 angular.module('testModule').factory("testService", function ($, $scope) {
    var proxy = null;
    alertService = function () {
        alert("servicePassed")
    }

    return {
        alertService: alertService
    }
 })
});
```

Any ideas??

Comment: The first thing that disturbs me is that `('StartCtrl', ['testService', function ($scope, testService)` should be `('StartCtrl', ['$scope', 'testService', function ($scope, testService)`.

Comment: Try @MarcelGwerder's comment. Or even better, don't "name" your services. For more info see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27589490/cant-access-my-service-in-my-controller-undefined/27589576#27589576

Comment: I tried what both suggestions, but to no luck . i'm getting following error: Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope <- testService